# Render one of child in vue template

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

How can I render one of $children in current vue template?

For example, I have a 3 $children, is it possible to render `this.$children[1]`?

`this.$children[1]` is looks like:

[image]

Comment: does my post answer your question ?

Comment: Looks as working approach, so probably yes. But I can't check this out right now

Answer (score 0):

You can use `render` function to achieve that. Imagine you have a `Parent` component, for which you want to always render just the first child. You use this component like this:

```
<Parent>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id, maiores.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id, maiores.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id, maiores.</p>
</Parent>
```

And this is how your parent component would look like:

```
<script>
  export default {
    render(createElement) {
      return createElement('div', [this.$slots.default[0]])
    }
  }
</script>
```

This is just to demonstrate the approach - this specific code will fail if you don't have any children - so you need to add a check for that in your render function.